# Angular 6 display image fetched from AWS S3

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am new on Angular 6 and stuck in a problem to get the image/doc/excel file from aws S3 bucket.

Here is my code:

```
var S3 = new AWS.S3();
    const params = {
      Bucket: 'asdasd',
      region: 'asadas1',
      accessKeyId: '[accessKeyId]',
      secretAccessKey: '[secretAccessKey]',
      
    }

    S3.listObjects(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('There was an error getting your files: ' + err);
        return;
      }

      console.log('Successfully get files.', data);

      const fileDatas = data.Contents;

      fileDatas.forEach(function (file) {
        
      });
    });
```

I got error:

```
MultipleValidationErrors: There were 3 validation errors:
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'region' found in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'accessKeyId' found in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'secretAccessKey' found in params
```

I want to fetch images from s3 and display them on my HTML page.

Comment: show what you tried, here's how to ask - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i didn't get anything yet regarding this url https://grokonez.com/frontend/angular-4-amazon-s3-example-get-list-files-from-s3-bucket  and that don't work for me..

Comment: Telling people who help you for free to do something ASAP is not really a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you used invalid Parameters to your API calls - the SDK doesn't know what to do with `region`, `accessKeyId` and `secretAccessKey`:

```
const params = {
  Bucket: 'asdasd',
  region: 'asadas1',                      // Here,
  accessKeyId: '[accessKeyId]',  // here
  secretAccessKey: '[secretAccessKey]',      // and here

}
```

Please see the [listObjects API Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjects-property) for reference.

Apparently your SDK isn't set up in the correct way, please see the documentation on how to do that.

- [Documentation for Server-Side JS-Code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html?shortFooter=true)
- [Documentation for Client-Side JS-Code - i.e. Angular](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-browser.html)

**Note: If you're using a Client-Side JS-Framework such as Angular, it is a terrible idea to hard-code security credentials! Your users will be able to see those and use them to access other resources. The documentation I linked above shows you better options.**

---

If you want to ignore Best Practices, **which you absolutely shouldn't**, this is how you could do it:

Set your AWS information at the beginning of your script as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html#constructor-property):

```
AWS.config.update({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    accessKeyId: "Don't do this",
    secretAccessKey: "It's a terrible idea!"
});
```

**Just to reiterate, it's a terrible idea to hard-code credentials in client-side code!**

Answer (score 0):

Try multer-s3 package in npm. I am using it and it works fine.

TIP: DO NOT EVER SHARE YOUR AWS KEY ID AND SECRET ID LIKE THIS... I REPEAT. DO NOT!!!!!.. Delete this post or make your access key inactive.