# How to view images from S3 bucket to my angular

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

I have to create a slide show image viewer using Angular 8 . My images are stored in the S3 browser how to fetch all the images from S3 bucket to my angular 8 project

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54002543/angular-6-display-image-fetched-from-aws-s3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know url from each image, you need developed a backend service for this.

If you use NodeJs try this [How to read data from AWS S3 in Node.JS](https://www.nixgyd.com/read-data-from-aws-s3-in-node-js-aws-sdk/363)

If you use .net try this [Get an Object Using the AWS SDK for .NET](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingNetSDK.html)

Regards